Does this kind of fan shaped multiplication table have a name? How was it used in teaching?
I got this fan shaped multiplication table from my parents when I was a kid in Sweden in the 80:s. I don't know exactly where it came from (the author is stated as Johan Göransson) and judging from the typography I would say it could originally be from around 1930--1960 (my copy is a facsimile).
Is there a name of this kind of fan shaped multiplication table and does it have special uses? How was it used in teaching?
Spontaneously I guess it could be useful for memorising the multiplication table in a more visual way than a text only table.

EDIT: I see there's a problem with the image on Stackexchange. Here's a link to the intended image: https://imgur.com/gUxkTVk

I don't know if it has a name sorry, very cool though! Never seen that before

@TobySaunders-A'Court, very interesting indeed! Also interesting that the poster in that link seems hand painted. It states the same author as my printed one.
